# Intent and AlertDialog in fragment not working

Tags: android, if-statement, android-fragments, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have a fragment that has some pictures, you select a picture and then press Next to go to another class to select Friends.

When you do not select a picture, I want to display an alert dialog otherwise they should go to select Friends.

```
protected TextView mMessage;
mMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text);
final String userMessage = mMessage.getText().toString();

mNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (userMessage.equals("") || userMessage.equals(null)) { 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageFragment.this.getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("oops");
            builder.setMessage("Make sure you take a pic");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            //blahh
        }
    }
});
```

The alert dialog shows even when I have text in the text view.

Comment: Can you tell us what errors you get.

Comment: (pictureFragment.this);*  // displays error  *(this, RecipientsActivity.class)*; // displays error,  its underlined in red in android studio

Comment: What message does Android Studio show when you hover over the red lines with your mouse?

Comment: can not resolve constructor intent

Comment: Please add your full Fragment class code so people can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the error appeared is because pictureFragment.this is a fragment. It must be an activity in order to work, so try this:

```
private TextView mMessage;
mMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

//On Button Click...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String userMessage = mMessage.getText().toString();
    if (userMessage.equals(null) || userMessage.equals("") || userMessage.isEmpty()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("oops");
        builder.setMessage("Make sure select a pic");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent (getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class);
        startActivity(recipientsIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: this shows and error mNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);and says this method is unreachable

Comment: Where does this piece of code is written? Inside the onClick? Please mention more details. :)

Comment: If it is inside the onClick method that I wrote above. Replace "view.findViewById" with "v.findViewById".

Comment: it says 'v' is unrecognized

Comment: I have just checked the edited question. Can you please edit it with your whole method code? Where did you write that exactly?

Comment: @smithyy Please update your question with your whole fragment code. The error must be in the button declaration. I need to know where did you write that exactly. :)

Comment: i had a return statement above the method hence the error, my mistake im very new to android. but alert view is not showing i changed it like you said

Comment: You must write return statement the last thing in your code. Return means to stop your code, so that's why it says button is unreachable if you have written the AlertDialog code after the return statement. Please try to write return statement the last thing in your code and tell me... Also switch it back with view.findViewById

Comment: works now but alert dialog not showing when i run my code

Comment: Did you registered your new intent in your AppManifest.xml? What happens exactly? What is working and not working?

Comment: yes when i press next and picture is selected it still moves onto recipient activity and does not show the alert like above in question

Comment: @smithyy This is supposed to happen. You wrote your AlertDialog code inside an if statement. First, it will check if mMessage is null or not. If it is null, it will show an AlertDialog. If it is not null, the intent of RecipientsActivity will be started. If you already know that, and the AlertDialog is not shown, please tell me what is mMessage then. String or object or what exactly...?

Comment: The message is string so will it work if I put mmessage == null

Comment: Alright I knew the reason now. If it is a string, you should write it like this: if (mMessage.equals(null) || mMessage.equals("")) { rest of code... } Tell me if that works for you or not.

Comment: @smithyy Note: "||" means "or". What this simply does is that it checks the two conditions written above together. If any of them is correct, it will show an AlertDialog. If that still doesn't work for you, it will be better to post your whole fragment code as the problem will be in the rest of your code, because what I said should work unless you wrote something else wrong... :)

Comment: i have tried it and it works but not the alert dialog wont go even if i type some text

Comment: Please post the part where you defined mMessage in your question. The problem must be in it.

Comment: @smithyy There was a problem in defining your TextView. I have changed the id of your TextView from "Text" to "text". So you must also fix it in your layout xml. Also private is better than protected in defining views. Give it a test and tell me. :)

Comment: @smithyy I have edited the answer again and again lol. The reason why the alert dialog was always shown is that the string was actually always null... I have moved that string declaration inside the onClick method of your button to check that string every time you click the button. Test it... :)

Comment: thank you so much for all your help it finally worked. :)

Comment: Glad you have finally made it! So long discussion... lol. You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the * and change this by:

```
    Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),RecipientsActivity.class);
    startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

or

```
    Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(pictureFragment.this.getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class.class);
    startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

Comment: it displays an error in the method mNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton); saying its unreachable

Comment: Declare the button as final Button mNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

Comment: Do you have a return or something before the declaration?

Comment: I think that the return is the problem

Comment: i moved it to the bottom it worked no errors but the alert dialog did not work

Comment: Try AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder*(getActivity()); or AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder*(pictureFragment.this.getActivity());

Comment: Did you check if it gets inside the if statement?Try this AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

Inside Fragments use getActivity() not this.

Try this;

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new  Intent(getActivity(),RecipientsActivity.class);
startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

Comment: it displays an error in the method mNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton); saying its unreachable

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide you full fragment code?